# jupyter notebook: use interact with constant function arguments

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I would like to know if it's possible to use interact in Jupyter with a function that would have non variable argument.
For example, in the function f below, I would like to have an interactive button only for arg b

```
def f(a, b=0):
    print (a*b)

a = 1
interact(f, a, b=(0,10,1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I used the the following synthax to solve my problem:

```
def f(a, b=0):
    print (a*b)
a = 1
interact(f, a=fixed(a), b=(0,10,1))
```